# New line after space

Tags: android

Is there a way to have a TextView that adds a new line after each space character in the text? For example, the text "one two three" should be displayed on 3 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you modify the text before it's added to the `ListView` to translate whitespace to newline?

```
String text = "one two three";
text.replaceAll("\\s", "\n");
```

Comment: I could. But I was wondering if there is an "automatic" way to do it. Like a combination of xml attributes.

Comment: I don't believe so - it's not something many people would find useful.  Correcting text before insertion is fairly standard pattern.